# lxml not performing xslt transform

Tags: python, xml, xslt, lxml

With this code:

```
from lxml import etree

with open( 'C:\\Python33\\projects\\xslt', 'r' ) as xslt, open( 'C:\\Python33\\projects\\result', 'a+' ) as result, open( 'C:\\Python33\\projects\\xml', 'r' ) as xml:
    s_xml = xml.read()
    s_xslt = xslt.read()
    transform = etree.XSLT(etree.XML(s_xslt))
    out = transform(etree.XML(s_xml))
    result.write(out)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
from projects.xslt_transform import trans
  File ".\projects\xslt_transform.py", line 17, in <module>
transform = etree.XSLT(etree.XML(s_xslt))
  File "xslt.pxi", line 409, in lxml.etree.XSLT.__init__ (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:150256)
lxml.etree.XSLTParseError: Invalid expression
```

this couple xml/xslt files works with other tools.

Also I had to get rid of the encoding attribute in the top declarations for both files in order not to get:

```
ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.
```

can it be related ?

**EDIT**:

this does not work either (i get the same error):

```
with open( 'C:\\Python33\\projects\\xslt', 'r',encoding="utf-8" ) as xslt, open( 'C:\\Python33\\projects\\result', 'a+',encoding="utf-8" ) as result, open( 'C:\\Python33\\projects\\xml', 'r',encoding="utf-8" ) as xml:
    s_xml = etree.parse(BytesIO(bytes(xml.read(),'UTF-8')))
    s_xslt = etree.parse(BytesIO(bytes(xslt.read(),'UTF-8')))
    transform = etree.XSLT(s_xslt)
    out = transform(s_xml)
    print(out.tostring())
```

reading lxml source code: this returns an exception:

```
xslt.xsltParseStylesheetDoc(c_doc)
```

so it seems an actual parse error. Can it be namespace related ?

**EDIT SOLVED**:

```
s_xml = etree.parse(xml.read())
s_xslt = etree.parse(xslt.read())
```

thanks tomalak

Comment: I'm not familiar with lxml, but what exactly is at line 409 of `xslt.pxi`?

Comment: it corresponds to line 399 in this one: https://github.com/lxml/lxml-maintenance/blob/master/src/lxml/xslt.pxi

code is nearly the same.

Comment: You cannot (should not) read XML files with `open()`. Use a parser. etree already does that (`etree.parse(filename)`). It will understand the encoding declaration and act accordingly without producing errors. I recon if you open the files correctly your other error will go away as well.

Comment: @Tomalak please put your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I don't get why you use `s_xslt = etree.parse(xslt.read())` when you can do `s_xslt = etree.parse('C:\\Python33\\projects\\xslt')`, but both variants are better than your initial attempt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parsing XML is more complicated than *"open a text file, stuff the resulting string into etree"*.

XML files are serialized representations of a DOM tree. They are not to be handled as text *even though* they come in the shape of a text file. They come in multiple byte encodings and finding out which encoding a certain file uses is anything but trivial.

XML parsers have proper detection mechanisms built in and therefore they should be used to open XML files. The the basic `open()` + `read()` calls are *not* enough to correctly handle the file contents.

`lxml.etree` provides [the `parse()` function](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-parse-function) that can accept a number of argument types:

> - an open file object (make sure to open it in binary mode)
> - a file-like object that has a .read(byte_count) method returning a byte string on each call
> - a filename string
> - an HTTP or FTP URL string

and then will correctly parse the associated document back into a DOM tree.

Your code should look more like this:

```
from lxml import etree

f_xsl = 'C:\\Python33\\projects\\xslt'
f_xml = 'C:\\Python33\\projects\\xml'
f_out = 'C:\\Python33\\projects\\result'

transform = etree.XSLT(etree.parse(f_xsl))
result = transform(etree.parse(f_xml))
result.write(f_out)
```